# Trying to detect the Enter key in JS

Tags: javascript

So I have a game, and Im trying to keep it from starting unless the user pressed the Enter key.

This is the code I have for that:

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
var enterpressed = 0; 
do {
    if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
        enterpressed = 13;
    }
    ctx.font = "25px Helvetica";
    drawStartScreen();
    update();
} while (enterpressed === 13);
```

This is the full program, on JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/3aoozxte/6/

Edit: I figured it out!
Here is the program working:
http://jsfiddle.net/84c2k5kg/6/

Comment: you don't seem to capture key presses anywhere that the tight loop can work on them.

Comment: The game responds to key presses cause I can move the snake around, so Im not sure what you mean?

Comment: `do { if (code == 13) { code = 13; } /* ... */ } while (code === 13);` That's... strange. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve there?

Comment: Im trying to exit the loop when the enter key is presseed

Comment: you set `code` before the tight loop, but within the loop you only set it if it is set to the number you're looking for. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Light, then there is, at the very least, an issue with the `while`'s conditional statement.

Comment: This is my first time programming JS, please understand that I am really trying. Im doing what makes sense to me, please explain if it doesnt to you.

The idea here is that I am setting code to 0, and then waiting for it to be set to 13 (when enter is pressed) and exit the loop. That is what I am trying to get

Comment: I edited the code above, let me know if that makes more sense.

Comment: @Light1c3: `if(code == 13) { code = 13; }` - That sets `code` to `13` if `code` is `13`. That is redundant. No point setting the variable to a value it already has. Anyway, please open the debugging console in your fiddle and fix the errors you see. Ones your code is running without errors please see if it works now or not. -- If you need to check if parts in your code are called or you need to validate variable values, use `console.log(variable)`.

Comment: @ François Wahl how do I debug?

Comment: @Light1c3: In Chrome hit the F12 key (I think most other browsers it's also F12). there you will see runtime errors and also have the ability to see your `console.log()` output. There is different tabs on the debugger console, the one you are most interested in for now is the `Console` I would say.

Comment: @ François Wahl: I found the issue, and I changed it to evt, but it still doesnt run correctly. It now says evt isnt defined but I use is in the other code so what's the issue here, scope?

Comment: JS is event-based. Blocking loops are never the good way.

Comment: See my answer for the solution. Another mistake in your code is your loop keeps going if you don't press enter. If you don't press enter, `enterpressed = 0` so it breaks out of your loop. It should be `!==` in your while statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem.

I added the enter key logic to your `keydown` eventlistener. So when you press enter it starts the game.
I deleted the loop in `startGameScreen()` to prevent the browser crashing repeating this infinite loop.
http://jsfiddle.net/3aoozxte/19/

```
function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = COLS*20;
    canvas.height = ROWS*20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    ctx.font = "12px Helvetica";

    frames = 0;
    keystate = {};
    started = false;

    // keeps track of the keyboard input
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
        keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
        if(keystate[Key_ENTER] && !started) { // Start the game if it's not started and Enter is pressed.
            started = true;
            init();
            loop();
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
    });

    //Attempting to create a welcome screen
    startGameScreen();
}

function startGameScreen() {
    ctx.font = "25px Helvetica";
    drawStartScreen();
}
```

Comment: That beautiful! Im trying to tweek it so that when they die it brings up the same screen. But hopefully I can do that myself!

Comment: If my code helped you, pls accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the one you are looking for.

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode == 90) {
    alert("Ctrl-Z was pressed");
}
else {
    var kc = evt.keyCode
    switch(kc){
        case 13 : alert("Enter was pressed"); break
        case 37 : alert("Left Key was pressed"); break
        case 38 : alert("Up Key was pressed"); break
        case 39 : alert("Right Key was pressed"); break
        case 40 : alert("Down Key was pressed"); break
       // default : alert(kc + " was pressed");//used to check for key value
    }
}
```

};

[Fiddle Key Events](http://jsfiddle.net/wLj1kft9/1/)

Adding the function on your listener..

```
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        started = true;
        init();
        loop();    
    }
}
```

[Updated and working Game](http://jsfiddle.net/3aoozxte/25/)

---

Complete reference [Complete Handling Key Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Answer (score -2):

I prefer using jquery

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    if (e.which == 13) 
    {
        //Your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post a solution to the issue in the desired/tagged language/library/technology **first** then off course in addition feel free to add alternative solutions.

Comment: How would I add this to my code though? I've never used jquery

Comment: Simple :) download lib on jquery.com and to header add script file:
<script src="./jquery-version.js"></script>
then you can add this code to <script>/*code*/</script>

Comment: @Light1c3: While I love jQuery, fix your logic first and then add jQuery if required. Learning another library while not having a working application in the first place is not wise. -- Your code currently seems to imply that you are new to JavaScript and have basic issues like trying to access undeclared variables, etc. jQuery is not going to solve that issue for you.

Comment: @Light1c3 include jquery source files using script tag and src attribute. <script `src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_install.asp